# Unable to set cookies from hosted backend (https://dev.abcd.com) to localhost of frontend

Tags: express, nginx, cookies, next.js14

I have tried many ways and different settings to set cookies on my browser.

Detailed scenario:
I am trying to build a authentication via social media.
When I am running frontend and backend both on localhost with different ports I am able to receive and send cookies.
But when i deployed code to the dev environment with different settings of cookie options {
httpOnly:true,
secure:false,
expiry://.....
}
I have all possible permutation combinations of these values and tried settings all required headers and cors configuration
Is it really impossible to set cookies on localhost from deployed backend over https?
One more thing is that I have configured nginx in between

I have tried all possible answers on internet